# rake routes with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the rake routes output for one of the urls

```
bug_info  /bugs/:pr/:scope/info(.:format)       {:controller=>"bugs", :action=>"info"}
```

Inside the erb view if i call bug_info_path(:pr=>1,:scope=>2), the view gives me an error saying

> No route matches {:scope=>"2", :action=>"info", :controller=>"bugs",
>   :pr=>"1"}

What am I doing wrong here

```
match 'bugs/:pr/:scope/info' => 'bugs#info', :as=>:bug_info
```

Comment: Try rename :scope, just guessing that it might collide with some rails parameter

Comment: Sure that BugsController have a info instance method?

Comment: I named it to "abcdef" and still got the same error

Comment: Yes. I have the info method. Otherwise the error would have been "no action" on the controller

Comment: Does it work if you remove one or all parameters in the match?

Comment: Yes. if i give the route as 'bugs/:pr/info' and call bug_info_path(:pr=>1,:scope=>2) the url is bugs/1/info?scope=2

Comment: It's possible that you need to restart your server. You usually don't need to in Development, but you may have your app configured in a way that requires it.

Comment: A bugs/:scope/info match works too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird. I tested by generating a new rails app and populated with your stuff and it seems to work fine. Here is what I got. (This is with Rails 3.0.7).

config/route.rb

```
Railstest::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'test' => 'bugs#test', :as=>:bug_test
  match 'bugs/:pr/:scope/info' => 'bugs#info', :as=>:bug_info
end
```

app/controllers/bugs_controller.rb

```
class BugsController < ApplicationController
  def test
  end

  def info
  end
end
```

app/views/bugs/test.erb

```
<%= bug_info_path(:pr=>1,:scope=>2) %>
```

app/views/bugs/info.erb

```
<%= params %>
```

When I browse to `/test` I get this:

> /bugs/1/2/info

When I browse to `/bugs/1/2/info`

> {"controller"=>"bugs", "action"=>"info", "pr"=>"1", "scope"=>"2"}

Maybe you could try with a minimal rails app too and then add things until i breaks.

Comment: I am going to try this with minimal app as said and test it

Comment: Nope, still the same error. I am running rails 3.1. However instead of :pr/:scope if i provide *pr/*scope then its running fine without any error

Comment: i got it. In my example, i was using the dynamic segment with a dot like /bugs/1/1.1/info. so it was failing. I added a constraint to scope to accept dot and it worked